# What's the best way to find the probability of 2 names having the same gematria (total numeric value?)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let's say you wanted to find the probability that someone's first name has the same simple gematria as his or her last name.

For example:

Using 1 for A, 2 for B, C for 3...Z is 26: a name like "Bob" is 2 + 15 + 2, or 19.  What's the probability his last name, whatever it is (doesn't matter), is also 19?

Question is generic to the quantity of first or last name.  I want to know the chances the first and last are the same.  E.g., 41 and 41, 24 and 24, 10 and 10, 61 and 61, etc.

I'm looking for a basic ballpark estimate.

Thanks!

Comment: There would need to be several assumptions made... It should be clear that not every name is equally likely to occur, and not every gematria is equally likely to occur either.  Further, a person's name and person's last name are not independently chosen.

Comment: That works...   now how do we go about it? :)

Comment: "*That works*"... I don't think you understood what I wrote at all... I wrote reasons why this is a hard problem, harder than you would otherwise realize, and harder than I can justify attempting.  You could try using a python script to loop over a phone book or three, but that would unfairly bias towards names who are likely to appear in such a phone book.  It is also not clear how you would treat names who are not written with the Latin alphabet (e.g. russian, chinese, japanese, arabic, etc...)

Comment: In addition, this is for English only, and the phonebook would indeed work as a dataset.

Comment: My comment was deleted somehow.  But basically, "that works" means "I agree with the starting parameters you set forth." I.e.,  I do fully understand the enormity of the actual task; that's why I phrased the question "what's the best way" only, not "can you execute xyz."